# In Turtle, how do I take stdout from a program, process it, and then supply something to stdin?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I am currently playing with format string attacks in C. I have a toy program that prints (to `stdout`) the address of a variable that I want to access, then accepts a line from `stdin` and `printf`s it..

Using Turtle, I'd like to be able to:

- execute the program
- parse the first few lines of `stdout` to retrieve the address
- using the address, craft a format string for `printf` (I know how to do this bit)
- write the attack string to `stdin`

However, I can't see how to do this. Using a function like `inshell :: Text -> Shell Line -> Shell Line`, I can supply some lines to `stdin` and get back a stream from `stdout`. However, I don't know how to inject new lines to `stdin` *after* having read a couple of lines from `stdout`.

Comment: I don't see why one would need Turtle for this; it's just basic IO. Since you know how to do step 3 already, your program is simply `getContents >>= putStrLn . makeFormatString`. Furthermore, `Shell` is an instance of `MonadIO` so if you really need a `Shell` you can convert the aforementioned program to a `Shell`.

Comment: I guess the attraction of Turtle was that it makes it easy to run the test program from inside Haskell. 

With this method, my understanding is that I would have to redirect the `stdout` of the test program into my Haskell program, and supply the `stdin` of the test program from a named pipe which I redirect the output of the Haskell program into. 

Is there an easy was to do this from Haskell itself?

Comment: If your goal is to test your program which performs IO, Turtle is the wrong tool for this. See for example [this](https://making.pusher.com/unit-testing-io-in-haskell/).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to test your program which performs IO you can use [`shelltestrunner`](https://github.com/simonmichael/shelltestrunner) (project written in Haskell) if you want to test I/O scenarios for every project (non necessarily written in Haskell).